# is it possible for '@ts-check' to run like typescript with strictNullChecks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I used typescript for a while and kinda liked it, except for the part that the compilation might take a pretty long-time.
Today I found that in vscode I could just write js code, and add some type-notation with jsdoc, and add a `//@ts-check` at the first line of the code.

but, I didn't have the same confidence in the code like I did with tsc with --strictNullCheck flag.

so, my question is, is it possible to run `//@ts-check` with strictNullCheck in js-code?

this is an example where I didn't get a compile error:

```js
// type.js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @typedef Foo
 * @property {string} foo
 * @property {string} [bar]
 */

 /** @type {Foo} */
 const a = { bar: 'test', foo: undefined }; // <- should be compile error
```

```js
// index.js
import * as T from './type';
/** @type {T.Foo} */
const a = {}; // <- should be compile error
a.foo.replace // <- will be runtime error.
```

Comment: I end up with just adding { tsnode: { transpileOnly: true }} in my tsconfig.json instead of looking for how to resolve the @ts-check with strictNullCheck.

because it reduce the time it takes to compile down from 60-ish second to 10 ~ 12 second.

which is good enough for me.